# Blender render says "No device available to denoise on"

Tags: rendering, error

every time I try to render my scene the render window says "no device available to denoise on" even though I have it set to CUDA with my RTX 2080ti and enabled GPU compute on the render window, also I have 64GB of Ram. If I need to provide more info about my pc let me know but this never happened before and now Im getting this problem. Here are some screenshots of the problem and my settings. Thank you.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: try an older and more stable version of the driver

Comment: What is your driver version?

Comment: Hey, I had the latest Game Ready Driver and switched to NVIDIA Studio Driver Version 512.96 Release Date: 05/23/2022. Both of them are giving me the same problem.

Comment: Also, when I restart my computer the renderer works just one time, and then if I try to render a frame again it gives me the problem.

Comment: @abdielfilms Does this happen with every file? Something like this happened to me but for something else, try switching your .blend file by opening a new file and copy-pasting the objects of the old file into your new file.

Comment: @YousufChaudhry I did what you recommended and its working for now, I'll keep testing it to see if the problem is fixed for good but maybe like you said there was something wrong with the .blend file. so thank you!

Also my scene needed a lot of optimization, I had some displacement meshes that did not wanted to render because I had the wrong settings. So practically I resolved the problem by doing that and reducing textures, vertices and polygons, joined objects, used more adequate render settings, fixed some errors I had in my materials and other small details.

Comment: UPDATE: Got the same problem after various renders. "No available device to denoise on". Sometimes I get it, sometime not.

Answer (score 1):

Is your hard drive full? Im currently working with blender files approx. 3 gig each, and blender auto saves your file, silently filling a hard drive pretty fast, with multiple 3 gig auto saves in my case. I stumbeled onto the same problem, and used WinDirStat (grand perspective if your on a mac) to find the culprit files, In my case 40% of the hard drive. Deleted the files and can now render more than one time. Does this work for you as well?